# PHP inside an <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

Tags: php

Building my first PHP site and need some help.

Trying to make it so that the domain name will be used for a directory.
Since I know this is a very broad question, the following will be the example of what I have and what I need.

```
$domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

if ($domain == 'website.com' || $domain == 'www.website.com') {
    $domain = 'Website';
    include ('Website/variables.php') ; } 
else { 
    $domain = 'Other';
    include ('Other/variables.php') ;
}
```

Now, what I need it to do is be able to place the `$domain` inside of an

```
link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet"
```

So what it should end up doing is actually using the `$domain` named folder like so

```
link href="$domain/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet"
```

No matter what I try to do, I just can not get my site to read into the directory of the domain that it is in which is stopping my `CSS` from working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: <link href=“<?php echo $domain; ?>” rel=“stylesheet”>

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
echo "<link href=' " . $domain . "/css/custom.css' rel='stylesheet'>";
```

Comment: For some reason, this just isn't working. Although I do see why it should.

Comment: Folder structure

index.php
    siteone dir
        custom.css

So your code should work, but it doesn't. That or I'm just screwed up somewhere else. (Which is most likely the case)

Comment: Why are you setting $domain to 'Website' or 'Other'? This might be why your css is not working. Also I wouldn't suggest to do this in the first place but I hope I've helped you.

Comment: I actually have 4 different websites. Each one has its own custom CSS and Images, so I put the site related items inside their own directory.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? If you really have 4 different websites why does it go to the same file?

Comment: All 4 are from a template. Only certain things from each site change. Colors, words used, and so forth. The layout never changes. I am trying to get it so that if you go to site A, it will use the correct wording colors, and so on from the PHP that is inside of its own folder. Same for site B C and D. So in short, each site calls upon two different PHPs for variables. The Default one, which all 4 call to, and the custom one which each site has in its own directory.

Comment: Another question as well. Would 

$domain = str_ireplace('.com', str_ireplace('www.', '', parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST)));

get the domain name and strip out the www and the .com leaving only the name of the domain. Meaning www.website.com would make $domain = website.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can do as..

```
<link href="<?php echo $domain; ?>/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Same thing only....